# What is the reason for encoding JWT?

Tags: encoding, base64, jwt

To the best of my knowledge regarding the security of JWT, if the JWT token doesn’t contain sensitive information, we only use its signature feature so that its content cannot be manipulated. Otherwise, if it contains sensitive data it can be encrypted to protect the data from sniffing. Also, both of them can be employed if needed.
However, what I cannot understand is that why the token is not a plain json? Why is it encoded while it can be easily decoded? Does it have a security reason or there is another reason behind that?
I searched the net and also took a quick look at [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) but I couldn’t find any clear and convincing answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly to ease processing of JWTs.

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by period ('`.`') characters.  Each part contains a base64url-encoded value.

This ensures both that a) the entire token is URL-safe, which simplifies things for a technology that's mostly used in a *web* context; and b) makes it easy to process "parts", since the part-separator ('`.`') is guaranteed to not occur inside the parts themselves. If it was plain JSON, a period may be anywhere within the encoded value itself, and you'd need to apply more complex JSON-aware parsing to find separate parts. But given the guarantee that a part cannot contain periods due to being base64url-encoded, the parsing algorithm is simple:

> 1. Verify that the JWT contains at least one period ('`.`') character.
> 2. Let the Encoded JOSE Header be the portion of the JWT before the first period ('`.`') character.
> 3. Base64url decode the Encoded JOSE Header following the restriction that no line breaks, whitespace, or other additional characters have been used.
>
> ...

(All excerpts from [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).)